# Passing an object from array using ngModel - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, parameter-passing

I have tow arrays in a parent component
one of them contains objects to be rendered in the HTML:

```
FieldsToRender:{Name:string,Id:number}[]
```

and another array to handle and save values:

```
values:{FieldId:number,Value:any}[]
```

my question is: how can I pass an object from Values array where the object has the same Id with the passed field from the array FieldsToRender to the child component??

Parent Component:

```
<app-chilComponent [FieldsToRender]="FieldsToRender" [recordValue]="???????"></app-childComponent>
```

Comment: Have a look at "*ngFor" as I think it will do what you want

Comment: I know about ngFor, but the problem here that I have two separated arrays and I need to pass an object from the first array with a condition from the other one @DaveWuzHere

Comment: I would try ngfor inside the ngfor with an ngif to compare the two